# Cobbler kickstart file for Fedora adding packages

Tags: fedora, kickstart, cobbler

Can I assume that if you add packages such as httpd and php these will be installed via "yum install" as long as I specify them after the %packages in the kickstart file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.

Here's a bit more documentation if you need more info

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-packageselection.html

Answer (score 1):

In a literal sense, no. The packages listed in the %packages section are installed by Anaconda, the Fedora installation program. This uses yum internally, but via API calls rather than exec'ing the `yum` command-line tool. That means the semantics of the install may differ slightly from what you get with `yum install` (particularly, the plugins configured will not necessarily be the same).

However, if the packages you specify are available in a configured repository at install time, the installer will pull them in and install the packages. And since `httpd` and `php` are of course part of the base Fedora release, unless you're doing something odd, putting them on the %packages section should just work.